# Laravel sql query works for Carbon all times except midnight

Tags: sql, laravel, database

i am trying to show a display schedule system and the logic is if departure time is greater than current time then dont show that schedule which then will show next time. this logic works fine for all times except when its midnight for some reason. current logic skips midnight times and jumps straight to 6:00am

```
$posts = DB::table('ferries')->groupBy('ferry_name')->orderBy('ferry_name', 'desc')
            ->where('schedule_type', '=', 'Holiday')
            ->where('departure_time', '>', Carbon::now()->toTimeString())
            ->where('terminal_name', $terminal_name)->get()->all();
```

Comment: try instead `Carbon::now()->endOfDay()->toTimeString()`

Comment: it returns null also `dd(Carbon::now()->endOfDay()->toTimeString());` returns "23:59:59" **EDIT**: the temporary fix was adding data directly from SQL with time sorted from 0:00 to end of the day but that is very inconvenient i would like to know why

Comment: try with `whereTime` as `whereTime('departure_time', '>', Carbon::now()->endOfDay()->toTimeString())`

Comment: same as before null cause endOfDay, i have to put earliest time at the top in sql for midnight times to show properly

Comment: midnight times dont show when i use `->groupBy('ferry_name')` works fine when i remove but then it is not grouped with different ferry names with times its repeated same names with different times. any alternatives for groupby